# Is there a Stack Exchange site to ask about Television Repair?

Tags: support, area-51, site-recommendation

I'm looking to manually update the firmware of my television, but I don't know where to get the firmware download from the internet.  I figured I'd ask on a Stack Exchange site, but I don't know which one would be relevant (maybe Home Repair comes closest, but that seems more contractor-based).  Either I just don't see it listed, or a relevant SE site for Electronics Repair doesn't exist, or it's not recognizably named (like when I didn't realize "Skeptics" encapsulated rumors, etc.).

I'm not sure where to ask where this sort of site exists, tossed a coin between Meta Stack Exchange (here) and Discussion for Area 51.  It landed heads side up, so I asked here.  Please point me in the right direction.

Note in the comments below, I did find the current Area 51 "[Consumer Electronics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics)" still in definition phase, and the died-in-beta "[Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets)", neither of which is helpful in this instance, though I did add my support to Consumer Electronics so at least someone wins... :-(

Answer (score 1):

[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is probably the closest.

Comment: I think not for a firmware question. That's more like if there was a superuser for ee.se.

Comment: I considered it or Super User, but it doesn't fall under either of their FAQs.  I found "Consumer Electronics" in Area51, which is still in definition and apparently a revisit to the 2-year-dead "Electronic Gadgets", which never survived beta phase.

Comment: Yeh, I didn't catch the firmware part, guess you'll just have to work to get the "Consumer Electronics" Area51 proposal going.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's anything that quite covers this right now; the problem faced by Gadgets (and probably CE as well) is that this subject tends to be ridiculously broad with relatively few experts.

Comment: I'd be more likely to suspect that Gadgets appeared too early in SE's lifecycle, but since CE isn't hopping... maybe it is the topic. :-/

Comment: Yeh, it's really really broad.